# Java Swing ActionListener not working

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

Can anyone help as to why this isn't working?

```
        menuItem = new JMenuItem("Document");
                menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            {
                                System.out.println("button clicked!");
                            }
                        });
        submenu.add(menuItem);
```

Thank you!

Comment: any erro you got in your console ???

Comment: The code you provided has a syntax error. Delete the third line entirely.

Comment: Please submit the hole class or even more code. From your code i don't see any error

Comment: Consider to use an Action object to configure your menu item: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("Document");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()   //You don't need it again.
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("button clicked!");
                        }
                    });
    submenu.add(menuItem);
```

try this:

```
menuItem = new JMenuItem("Document");
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                    {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                        {
                            System.out.println("button clicked!");
                        }
                    });
    submenu.add(menuItem);
```

Comment: Ahhh I didn't see the duplication!! Thank you

Comment: @Arpit i think that was just a duplicate

Comment: @FestusTamakloe you can vote for close :)